# how to solve in $\Bbb{R}$ the inequality $(x-3)(x+1)<0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Solve the following inequality in $\Bbb{R}$:
> $$(x-3)(x+1)<0$$

My answer was:
$$x^2+x-3x-3<0 \\
x^2+x-3x<+3 \\
x^2-2x<3 
$$
what should i do next,is it a remarkable identity?
i dont know how to continue.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Hint: it's better not to multiply out that expression. A product is negative just when its two factors have opposite sign. When does that happen in this example? (There's won't be a formula for the answer.(

Comment: $x^2-2x<3\iff (x-1)^2<4$

Answer (score 5):

Note that the product of two positive quantities or two negative quantities is positive,

but the product of a negative quantity and a positive quantity is negative.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

$$(x-3)(x+1)<0$$
The product of two factors is negative when both factors have opposite signs. So that you have to solve these inequalities:

1. $$ x-3 >0 \text { and } x+1 <0$$
   Or:
2. $$x-3 <0 \text { and  } x+1>0$$

Answer (score 0):

If you want to think geometrically, the graph of $y=(x-3)(x+1)$ is an upward opening parabola that intersects the $x$-axis at $x=-1$ and at $x=3.$ We have $y$ negative for $x$ between the two roots, that is, for $-1<x<3,$ which provides the solution to the original inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to think of when the factors vanish. This helps you form an idea of the range where they are negative, and where positive. Then you're interested in finding the range where their product is negative.